# php: множественное наследование абстрактных классов

Tags: php

Как известно, php не поддерживает множественное наследование. Но почему такой код отрабатывает?

```
<?php
// Parent class
abstract class CParent{
    abstract public function demo();
}

// Наследование раз
abstract class p1 extends CParent{
    abstract public function simple();
}

// Наследование два
class CChild1 extends p1{
    public static function create(){
        return new static();
    }

    public function demo(){
        echo "OK\n";
    }

    public function simple(){
        echo "called simple function\n";
    }
}

CChild1::create()->demo(); // Выведет "ОК"
```

Comment: потому что это банальное наследование?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, во всех книгах, которые я читал, четко и ясно написано: php не поддерживает множественное наследование (есть интерфейсы, трейты и т.д.).
Меня интересует, что я неправильно понял в этой концепции и почему не вылетает error, а вместо этого код успешно отрабатывает

Comment: множественное наследование это когда  `class CChild1 extends p1, p2, p3{`.... а то что ты описал - это простое наследование, тут нет множественного....... ты любой класс можешь наследовать от любого....то, что у тебя два абстрактных класса подряд - не делает это наследование множественным

Comment: более того, можно даже вот так писать `abstract class A {
  
}

class B extends A {
}

abstract class C  extends B {
}

class D  extends C  {
}`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, большое спасибо! докатился я

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день. 
Потому что это не множественное наследование, а обычное. Для множественного наследования должна быть вот такая запись

```
abstract class CParent {
    abstract public function demo();
}

abstract class CParent2 {
    abstract public function simple();
}

class CChild1 extends CParent, CParent2 {
}
```

В вашем примере классы наследуются друг от друга, по-порядку. При множественном наследовании они должна наследоваться одновременно

Comment: капец. Что ж я мучился тогда так долго!
Огромное спасибо вам за разъяснение!